# Generic data access class with different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an application where I can choose a database with the help of a combobox and then apply several query operations on this database within application. For this purpose, I have generated 6 different `.edmx` files which is generated from my databases with the database first approach. Besides that, I want to create a **Data Access Layer** class where I am managing my data access operations, but I want this class to be generic so that I am not going to need to create 6 different data access classes for each entity. For this purpose, I created such a class;

```
public class UserDetails<TEntity> where TEntity:class
    {
        private DbContext _context { get; set; }
        private DbSet<TEntity> efDB { get; set; }

        public UserDetails(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            efDB = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        public List<UserDetailsModel> GetUserDetails(int? roleID, int? titleID, int? managerID, string id = "", string name = "", string surname = "", string mail = "")
        {
            using (efDB) {

                List<UserDetailsModel> query = (from user in efDB.TABLE_USER
                                                join pass in efDB.TABLE_PASSWORD_HISTORY on GetLatestPassword(user.ID) equals pass.ID into passJoined
                                                from passLatest in passJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                join role in efDB.TABLE_REL_USER_ROLE on user.ID equals role.UserID into roleJoined
                                                from roleRel in roleJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                join defRole in efDB.TABLE_DEF_ROLE on roleRel.RoleID equals defRole.ID into defRoleJoined
                                                from defRoleRel in defRoleJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                join title in efDB.TABLE_USER_TITLES on user.TitleID equals title.ID
                                                where user.Name.Contains(name) && user.Surname.Contains(surname) && user.Email.Contains(mail)
                                                select new UserDetailsModel() {
                                                                                ID = user.ID,
                                                                                Name = user.Name,
                                                                                Surname = user.Surname,
                                                                                Email = user.Email,
                                                                                TitleID = (int)user.TitleID,
                                                                                TitleName = title.Description,
                                                                                Password = passLatest.Password,
                                                                                RoleID = roleRel.RoleID,
                                                                                RoleName = defRoleRel.RoleName,
                                                                              }
                                               ).ToList();

                return query;
            }
```

As you see, I want to perform a linq query in my `GetUserDetails` method. Note that, all of the 6 databases have same tables with the same names so that this query is going to work for all of my entities. What I want to do here is that, use the variable `efDB`generically so that it can be any of the 6 database entites. The desired database entity instance will be created by a different class which works like a factory and will be given to my `UserDetails` data access class. But obvisiouly, my code won't work. How can I implement this generic logic into my system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``But obvisiouly, my code won't work``: why doesn't it work? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like UnitOfWork. Here are a few links describing and explaining how to set one up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770156/Understanding-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern

https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern/